# PHP: DATETIME in array as object. How to echo

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, object

Hope that title isn't too cryptic. I have an array with a DATETIME object in it and I'm just trying to figure out how to echo this to a page.

```
 ["created"]=> object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2010-10-22 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London"
```

Can someone help me out?

tried date() but get:

```
Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in C:\
```

any help most appreciated,

Jonesy

Comment: echo ((array)myArray["created"])['date'];
or u can ->format(DateTime::DATE_FORMAT_CONST);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
echo date_format(myArray["created"], "the format you want for your date");
```

Formatting:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 11):

Use [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). The mask syntax is identical to `date()`'s.

```
echo $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 11):

I add this answer even if I am not sure it answers specifically the question (and best answer is already there though),
but I couldn't find much other places where the above format (`date`/`timezone_type`/`timezone`) is mentioned.

If you have the date translated from object to array

- via `var_export`

`DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2017-12-05 11:58:25.428595',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'US/Pacific',
))`

- or `json_encode`

`{"date":"2017-12-05 11:57:07.938671","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"US\/Pacific"}`

you can use again the `DateTime::__set_state` magic method mentioned above to **convert it again to a *DateTime* object**.

Not sure how here `__set_state` could bidirectional, but it **does the magic**.
I couldn't find documentation.

But you can test it here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a18e6937e7d4373beb91713f2e6e5f75f9af3e2

Comment: off topic but usefull.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an actual php5 [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object then you can use the `format` method to echo it

```
$myDate = $myArray['created'];
echo $myDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```